# Unable to locate .sencha folder

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

(1) I use Ext JS 6.5 on macOS 10.12.5 .

(2) I am reading guideline at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/guides/quick_start/going_to_production.html .

(3) Download https://github.com/sencha-extjs-examples/QuickStart/archive/master.zip

(4)unzip, rename directory `QuickStart-master` to `QuickStart`.

(5) Ext JS 6.5 (after unzip) put in `/Users/donhuvy/Downloads/ext-6.5.0`.

I run

```
cd /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/QuickStart
sencha app install --framework=/Users/donhuvy/Downloads/ext-6.5.0
```

I see error:

```
➜  ~ pwd                                                              
/Users/donhuvy
➜  ~ cd /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/QuickStart
➜  QuickStart sencha app install --framework=/Users/donhuvy/Downloads/ext-6.5.0
Sencha Cmd v6.5.0.180
[INF] Using existing workspace at /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/QuickStart
[INF] Copying framework to /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/QuickStart/ext
[INF] Loading configuration for framework directory: /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/QuickStart/ext
[INF] Upgrading to Ext JS 6.x
[INF] Upgrading to sdk at /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/QuickStart/ext
[ERR] Unable to locate .sencha folder
[ERR] Please ensure this folder is a valid v3 ExtJS application
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExScript: com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: No .sencha directory found (anonymous#27)
   runAppUpgrade (anonymous:26)
   [anonymous] (anonymous:464)
   x_app_upgrade (anonymous:463)
➜  QuickStart sencha app install --framework=/Users/donhuvy/Downloads/ext-6.5.0
Sencha Cmd v6.5.0.180
[INF] Using existing workspace at /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/QuickStart
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps from the start

1. Download https://github.com/sencha-extjs-examples/QuickStart/archive/master.zip
2. Open Terminal
3. Type the following:

   ```
   cd Downloads
   unzip QuickStart-master.zip
   mv QuickStart-master QuickStart
   cd QuickStart
   sencha app upgrade /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/ext-6.5.0
   sencha app build
   sencha app watch
   ```

   When you see

   ```
   [INF] Waiting for changes...
   [LOG] Fashion waiting for changes...
   ```

   Leave the app running, don't close the Terminal or Hit Control+C
4. Access: http://localhost:1841/

(Remember: Clear browser's cache)

Comment: It is the same result.

Comment: Weird, I got the same result as you did with `sencha app install` but it worked with `sencha app upgrade`. You should have seen 

[INF] Upgrading framework ext
[INF] Copying framework to /Users/donhuvy/Downloads/QuickStart/ext
[INF] Framework 'ext' upgraded

Comment: After apply my steps, also apply your steps, when I access http://localhost:1841 I see nothing, but when `View Page Source`, I see webpage has HTML content inside.

Comment: I updated my answer to a step-by-step of what I did. This should show you the app

Comment: Thank @Guilherme Lopes, this is my result: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/d238d54fed49eebed4b9357c45e08562 a blank HTML webpage with HTML source inside.

Comment: If you are running the code above ^^, why is your project named erp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147505/discussion-between-guilherme-lopes-and-do-nhu-vy).